# IDEA's "Missing require() statement" inspection highlights "JSON"

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

When writing Node.js apps in Intellij IDEA, the "Missing require() statement" inspection complains about any use of `JSON`.

For example, the following line is flagged: `var some_object = JSON.parse(some_json_text);`

It then recommends adding `var JSON = require("path")` as the fix, which is obviously incorrect. The code still runs just fine, obviously, but the faulty inspection is frustrating.

There's a similar problem when using Mocha or Chai, which is solved by adding some DefinitelyTyped libraries. Is there perhaps a library that I'm missing for this?

Thanks,
James

**Edit:
Ctrl+clicking on it provides these:
[image: declaration options]

Comment: doesn't happen to me. Try ctrl+clicking on `JSON` - what declaration are you taken to?

Comment: @lena, I edited my post with a picture. Hopefully this gives some insight?

Comment: not much. If JSON is resolved to some property in a module, then a suggestion to import it is expected

Comment: And that's what's weird, @lena, no import is actually needed. `JSON` is just part of the JS engine. It's purely IDEA's inspection being fussy.